# How do I build the ManDVD package from compressed source on Linux?

Tags: linux, makefile, installation, maya, xfce

When I try to install any compressed file into Linux I never can, because:

1. When I execute `./configure` the system says `bash: ./configure: No such file or directory`.
2. When I execute `sudo ./configure` the system says `sudo: ./configure: command not found`.
3. Worst , when I execute `make` the system says  make: `*** No rule to make target '/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/mkspecs/default/qmake.conf', needed by 'Makefile'.  Stop.`
4. With `make install` the system says `make: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/mkspecs/default/qmake.conf', needed by 'Makefile'.  Stop.`
5. Completion: I can't install nothing that is not in the repository into my system.

Note: I use Linux Mint XFCE 13 (Maya).

What can I do to solve this unpleasant problem?

Comment: What project are you trying to make? Can you post it's makefile? Seems there's no `configure` script on the folder, and maybe reading the `makefile` we can see what are the targets. Or maybe try `qmake` first, perhaps it does the trick.

Comment: I'm trying to make ManDVD Project http://mandvd.softonic.com/linux

Comment: The two standard questions when `./configure` does not work are: (1) What does the README file say? (2) If the README file doesn't say how to build or where to look for build information, what does the INSTALL file say?  If you cannot find either of those files, look around at what's in the directory and see what you can find.  If you can't find a `configure` script or instructions on how to build the project, then maybe you shouldn't waste your time trying.

Answer (score 0):

As [ManDVD's `Makefile`](https://gist.github.com/4158962) says:

```
#############################################################################
# Makefile for building: mandvd
# Generated by qmake (1.07a) (Qt 3.3.8b) on: Sun Mar  8 18:32:50 2009
# Project:  mandvd.pro
# Template: app
# Command: $(QMAKE) -o Makefile mandvd.pro
#############################################################################
```

Makefile was autogenerated by `qmake`.

I'm no expert at using `qmake`, but I think executing `qmake` will re-generate `Makefile`, so then you can run `make && sudo make install` as `INSTALL` file says.

You should've already discovered project is kind of messy (if not discontinued at all), so take care, and may the force be with you :)